# Mapinfo incorrect polyline (boundary) map to region conversion

Tags: mapinfo, polyline-creation, region

How to solve issue regarding incorrect boundary to region conversion? I have boundary map plotted on cosmetic layer when I convert it to region it results in line with overlap to other region.
The two images are :
    [image]
[image]
How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: How did you draw the boundary?

Comment: @Hairy  No I did not ? :(

Comment: How was the boundary drawn?  BTW, I cannot see the images

Comment: @Hairy I have changed the image to jpg format it was png initially. I don't have much information about how the image was created :( . Any solution !!

Comment: I can't comment without seein ght eimage and knowing how thy were created; could be a load of lies and polylines, which would create the overlap

Comment: @Hairy Whats "ght eimage"??

Comment: seeing the image - seein ght eimage

Comment: @Hairy hahaha I loaded the image though and Thanks for response :)

Comment: I still cannot see it unfortunately!

Comment: @Hairy I change the image format to .gif now you might be able to see it :)

Comment: I think the problem is that your polyline consists of several segments and that they are not snapped closely together

Comment: @Peter Horsbøll Møller Yes the table of polyline had segments but I combined the object of polygon with a column having  same id. Is there any solution to this problem ?

Comment: I found that it has line intersection each other rather than continuous line and line that are not intersecting when zoomed in . Any solution?

Comment: Did you use Objects>Combine and use the ID?

Comment: @Hairy yes I did :)

Comment: Coo, you have the answer anyway, and it's the approach I would have used, I didn't get what you were trying, as I couldn't see the pictures. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disaggregate the original multipart polyline (*Objects > Disaggregate*), then examine each constituent polyline and ensure that the ends are snapped to the adjacent line section so that there aren't any gaps. Finally recombine the polyline parts (*Objects > Combine*) and convert the result to a region.